# sudo password required with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql-workbench, sudo

I have MySQL Server and MySQL Workbench installed on my Mac running OS X 10.8.2.
I was having no problems until I tried to increase the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` by changing the configuration file. Since then, if I try to access the Server Logs, Configuration File or Users and Privileges, I am asked to enter a sudo password. However, the dialogue box indicates the username as `'Nick'` and my Mac OS username is `'Nick Francis'`. I have tried the root password and my usual user password, but neither work. How can I change the user or reset the password? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Manage Server Instances and select the instance you wanna change. Switch to the System Profile tab. There's a field "Sudo command". There you can enter your password. Use the command shown there in a terminal to verify it works as expected or change it what fits best for you.